# Administrator overrides in Joomla 3

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I'm trying to override

```
/administrator/components/com_media/views/imageslist
```

to make a more userful display, as the list loads very slow when there are a lot of large images in the folders. However, I'm unable to make the override work: 
I have copied the files

```
/administrator/components/com_media/views/imageslist/tmpl/default.php and 
/administrator/components/com_media/views/imageslist/tmpl/default_image.php
```

to

```
/administrator/templates/isis/html/com_media/imageslist
```

isis is set up as the default admin template in the installation. When displaying com_media in administrator (in an iframe), the following url is used:

```
/administrator/index.php?option=com_media&view=imagesList&tmpl=component&folder=
```

but it always loads using the files directly from com_media, and not from the template override. (I have noticed that the view says imagesList, while the folder name is imageslist).  It might just be a bug in joomla. Any ideas?

regards Jonas

Edit: Tried to dig deeper in this. It seems that when JViewLegacy calls loadtemplate, the paths look like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => /home/XXX/www/administrator/components/com_media/views/imageslist/tmpl/ 
[1] => /home/XXX/www/administrator/templates/isis/html/com_media/imageslist/ 
[2] => /home/XXX/www/administrator/components/com_media/views/imageslist/tmpl/ )
```

so even thought the path to the override is in the paths, it is not hit as the first, and it is the files in the original component that is loaded instead of the overrides. However, I still don't know why this happens. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The post is 9 month old, but I have the same strange behavior ... The trouble is in the com_media controller ... specificaly, the component adds the template path to path list in the line 68 ...

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/administrator/components/com_media/controller.php#L68

I removed the line in the core component the overriding works.

Comment: Hi Silvio, good job. I haven't looked into this since my post. Will you report this as a bug to joomla?

Comment: Yes, yesterday I add a note in the project ... https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/commit/fe5e4547835b2aa77a4b277cf229757a21e20c3c ... I don't know if the pull request mentioned by dgt41 will be accepted, but this change is fine for me ...   https://github.com/dgt41/joomla-cms/commit/74ae7e732ac205ea2a45ffa5068f640b81d6dc63#diff-46853d5c602b247ad0d2954fc28d7510L68

Answer (score 1):

That's very interesting and I think it has to do with using the component format rather than the html one ... if you look in the plugin you'll see the link looks like this:

`$link = 'index.php?option=com_media&amp;view=images&amp;tmpl=component&amp;e_name=' . $name . '&amp;asset=' . $asset . '&amp;author=' . $author;`

The fact that tmpl=component means that it is not going to use index.php, it is going to use component.php.

I haven't dug into the code further than that, but I think the override is not going to work because of that.

Comment: Hmm, I tried to debug this now, but did not really find the error. It clearly does not depend on the tmpl=component - bit, the error is the same when I remove this.

Comment: Wow that order issue is definitely key.  That's definitely not the standard behavior

Answer (score 0):

For com_media overrides, one way I solve this is by creating a system plugin with an onAfterRoute() event handler to capture and evaluate the request URL parameters. Then I can set a template override path and use an include for my views and templates. My example system plugin code in /plugins/system/mycommedia/mycommedia.php,

```
// no direct access
defined ( '_JEXEC' ) or die ( 'Restricted access' );

jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin');

class plgSystemMyComMedia extends JPlugin { 

    public function onAfterRoute() {

        if('com_media' == JRequest::getCMD('option')) {

            $view = JRequest::getCMD('view');

            if (('images' == $view) || ('imageslist' == $view)) {

                $overridePath = FOFPlatform::getInstance()->getTemplateOverridePath('com_media', true) . '/' . $view;

                require_once $overridePath . '/view.html.php';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This version of the onAfterRoute() function above shows how to apply the override for just the backend (admin) views and templates.

```
public function onAfterRoute() {

    $app = JFactory::getApplication();

    if ($app->isAdmin()) {

        if('com_media' == JRequest::getCMD('option')) {

            $view = JRequest::getCMD('view');

            if (('images' == $view) || ('imageslist' == $view)) {

                $overridePath = FOFPlatform::getInstance()->getTemplateOverridePath('com_media', true) . '/' . $view;

                require_once $overridePath . '/view.html.php';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Create the new custom templates and views by copying from the the com_media component into your template folders. For example, if you want to customize media manager for your administrator isis template:

copy
/administrator/components/com_media/views/images
to
/administrator/templates/isis/html/com_media/images

copy
/administrator/components/com_media/views/imageslist
to
/administrator/templates/isis/html/com_media/imageslist

Then modify both copies of view.html.php to include their respective default template copies.

At the end of the display function, comment out or replace,

```
parent::display($tpl);
```

with an include directive to the template copy,

```
include( dirname(__FILE__) . '/tmpl/default.php');
```

Also comment or replace both loadTemplate('folder') and loadTemplate('image') function calls in the imageslist default template to include their respective file and folder default template copies.

For example, in /administrator/templates/isis/html/com_media/imageslist/tmpl/default.php

```
<?php for ($i = 0, $n = count($this->folders); $i < $n; $i++) :
    $this->setFolder($i);
    //echo $this->loadTemplate('folder');
    include( dirname(__FILE__) . '/default_folder.php');
endfor; ?>

<?php for ($i = 0, $n = count($this->images); $i < $n; $i++) :
    $this->setImage($i);
    //echo $this->loadTemplate('image');
    include( dirname(__FILE__) . '/default_image.php');
endfor; ?>
```

The com_media views and templates will now be loaded instead of their core counterparts and can be customized without hacking any core Joomla files.

More info @ http://jimfrenette.com/joomla/customizing-joomla-media-manager/